# How to establish relation with respect to higher ranked trait bounds

Tags: rust, lifetime

I am trying to create a high order function which takes in (a function that takes &str and returns iterator of &str). What I am having difficulty is to relate lifetime variables of `for<'a>` for the function and the return type of that function. It is hard to describe in words, so let's jump right into the code:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader, Result};

fn static_dispatcher<'b, I>(
    tokenize: impl for<'a> Fn(&'a str) -> I,
    ifs: BufReader<File>,
) -> Result<()>
where
    I: Iterator<Item = &'b str>,
{
    ifs.lines()
        .map(|line| tokenize(&line.unwrap()).count())
        .for_each(move |n| {
            println!("{n}");
        });
    Ok(())
}

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let ifs = BufReader::new(File::open("/dev/stdin")?);
    static_dispatcher(|line| line.split_whitespace(), ifs)
    // static_dispatcher(|line| line.split('\t'), ifs)
}
```

The compiler complains that the lifetime relation of the `tokenize`'s input `'a` and output `'b` is not specified.

```
  --> src/main.rs:21:30
   |
21 |     static_dispatcher(|line| line.split_whitespace(), ifs)
   |                        ----- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
   |                        |   |
   |                        |   return type of closure is SplitWhitespace<'2>
   |                        has type `&'1 str`
   |
   = note: requirement occurs because of the type `SplitWhitespace<'_>`, which makes the generic argument `'_` invariant
   = note: the struct `SplitWhitespace<'a>` is invariant over the parameter `'a`
   = help: see <https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html> for more information about variance
```

I want to specify 'a = 'b, but I can't because 'a comes from `for<'a>`, which is not visible for the type `I`.

I also tried

```
fn static_dispatcher<'a, I>(
    tokenize: impl Fn(&'a str) -> I,
    ifs: BufReader<File>,
) -> Result<()>
where
    I: Iterator<Item = &'a str>,
```

but this does not work either b/c the lifetime of `tokenize` argument must be generic, i.e., must be used with for `<'a>`.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You could try creating a custom trait using the finally-added support for generic associated types (GATs): https://blog.rust-lang.org/2022/10/28/gats-stabilization.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom trait:

```rust
trait IteratorReturningSingleArgFn<Arg>: Fn(Arg) -> Self::Iter {
    type Iter: Iterator<Item = Self::Item>;
    type Item;
}

impl<Arg, F, Iter> IteratorReturningSingleArgFn<Arg> for F
where
    F: Fn(Arg) -> Iter,
    Iter: Iterator
{
    type Iter = Iter;
    type Item = Iter::Item;
}

fn static_dispatcher(
    tokenize: impl for<'a> IteratorReturningSingleArgFn<&'a str, Item = &'a str>,
    ifs: BufReader<File>,
) -> Result<()> {
    // ...
}
```

This makes inference mad (and I can understand it :) ) and requires you to specify the type in the closure inside `static_dispatcher()` explicitly:

```rust
    ifs.lines()
        .map(|line: Result<String>| tokenize(&line.unwrap()).count())
```

And in `main()`:

```rust
static_dispatcher(|line: &str| line.split_whitespace(), ifs)
```

But unfortunately it still doesn't work: because of the nasty lifetime inference in closures, the compiler doesn't use HRTB lifetime here and instead try to apply concrete lifetimes. This can be fixed by using the nightly [`closure_lifetime_binder`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/97362) feature:

```rust
#![feature(closure_lifetime_binder)]

static_dispatcher(for<'a> |line: &'a str| -> std::str::SplitWhitespace<'a> { line.split_whitespace() }, ifs)
```

Or by using a function instead of a closure:

```rust
fn tokenize(line: &str) -> impl Iterator<Item = &str> {
    line.split_whitespace()
}
static_dispatcher(tokenize, ifs)
```